# Trying to have two side by side buttons that change text when clicked on

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make two buttons stand side by side 
when clicked on one should say "im right" and the other says "no im right!"

```
<button id="right" type="button">Click Me!</button>
<button id="wrong" type="button">Click Me!</button>
```

This is my Html.

I am new to Javascript so I am having some trouble putting this together in a function.

```
 document.getElementById("right").addEventListener("click", function(){
               alert("I am Right!");
  });
 document.getElementById("wrong").addEventListener("click", function(){
               alert("No,I'm Right!");
  });
```

rather than have an alert I want to have the button's change to that text when clicked on.

Comment: No... I am right.

Comment: Your function doesn't do anything with the param you are passing, nor does it address the second button.

Comment: It's also `innerHTML` not `innerHtml`

Comment: First of all, please format your code. Put a semi-colon at the end of a statement in JavaScript, and Html and HTML are not the same things. HTML means HyperText Markup Language, while Html makes it seem like it's not an abbreviation.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function swapText(buttonClicked){
  
  var button1 = document.getElementById('button1');
  var btn1Output = document.getElementById('btn1Output');
  var btn2Output = document.getElementById('btn2Output');
  
  if (buttonClicked == button1){
    btn1Output.innerHTML = "I'm right.";
    btn2Output.innerHTML = "No, I'm right.";
  } else {
    btn1Output.innerHTML = "No, I'm right.";
    btn2Output.innerHTML = "I'm right.";
  }
}
```

```css
button, div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 45%;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="swapText(this)" id="button1">Click</button>
<div id="btn1Output"></div>
<button onclick="swapText(this)" id="button2">Click</button>
<div id="btn2Output"></div>
```

Comment: At least provide an explanation, and, in addition, I think he meant to have a span that has the results "I'm right!"/"No, I'm right!", and the buttons should say "Right" or "Wrong".

Comment: Im sorry I wasnt clear I meant that I wanted two button named "click" then one button says "im right!" and the other says "no im right!"

Comment: Edited the original.  Not much to explain here

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
  function myFunction(isRight) {
    if(isRight) {
      alert('It is right button');
    } else {
      alert('It is left button');
    }
  }
</script>

<button class="left" onclick="myFunction(false)">Left</button>
<button class="right" onclick="myFunction(true)">Right</button>
```

You could use something like that for the sample.
But I recommend look to [addEventLister](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and [Event Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget) it will looks good.